# Is it possible to store the previous value of a variable after it changes?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've been playing around with batch recently, and I'm trying to write a  generator that stores each value generated.

The generator is in one label:

```
:gene2
  set /a wid= %RANDOM% * (%maxval% - %minval% + 1) / 32768 + %minval%
  set /a hei= %RANDOM% * (%maxval% - %minval% + 1) / 32768 + %minval%
  set /a dep= %RANDOM% * (%maxval% - %minval% + 1) / 32768 + %minval%
  set /a vol= %wid% * %hei% * %dep%
  set /a flo= %wid% * %dep%
```

The generator is suppose to be able to run 5 times and remember each number generator for `%vol%`.
How do you store the value of `%vol%` before the generator resets? Because when all 5 results are made (`%vol1%` through `%vol5%`), they are all the same value as the first value that was generated.

Comment: Try `SETLOCAL` ... `ENDLOCAL` pair. [More here](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) incl. examples.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by %vol1% through %vol5% because I do not see those variables or how you are "storing" them.

However if this batch file is getting called 5 times by clicking on the same batch file. Then each time the batch file is in a different cmd session therefore the values set in the variables are lost.

To keep track of your generated variables I would suggest writing them to a file for retrieval later.

You could do something like

```
set /a vol= %wid% * %hei% * %dep% 
echo %vol%>>C:\MyVars\vols.txt
```

If you use ">>" you will append the file or you could use ">" to overwrite the file on each run.

At the beginning of the batch file read in the vols.txt file like

```
set /p Vol=<C:\MyVars\vols.txt
```

Then you have the previous vol value in the next session.

If you add more information on what you are trying to achieve I may be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. I did this: At the beginning, I said `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and then `set /a index= 1`. Then to calculate volume using the same labels I said `set /a vol%index%=%wid%*%hei%*%dep%` and it worked. It can now generate indefinitely.